# regex of the given pattern

Tags: python-re

Given the following line, I want to get each single `/* ... */` case, like:

```
/* ty=Tensor[(32, 3, 6, 6), int8] */
```

How should I write the re pattern?

```
 %6 = nn.conv2d(%5, meta[relay.Constant][0] /* ty=Tensor[(32, 3, 6, 6), int8] */, strides=[2, 2], padding=[0, 0, 0, 0], channels=32, kernel_size=[6, 6], out_dtype="int32") /* ty=Tensor[(1, 32, 320, 320), int32] */;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following RegEx will work:

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
```

- Match the start of the comment: `\/\*`
- Match any text between: `*.?`
- Match the end of the comment: `\*\/`